# Set focus to element of nested component in Angular 4

Tags: angular

In angular 4, I have a component nested inside of another. The inner or the child component contains: a button, an input and a drop down list.
On the parent page, when I click on the button, both the input and the drop-down are displayed.

What is a good way to set focus of the input when clicking the button?

What I tried so far:
In the child component, I added an id on the input: `<input #inputId ... >`, then in the same method triggered when the button is pressed, in the child component, I added:

```
$('#inputId').focus();
```

But this has no effect...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation `#inputId` isn't something you can search for using a jQuery selector. What that notation gives you is something you can access from the parent component with a declaration like this:

```
  @ViewChild('inputId') myInput: ElementRef;
```

Once you have this element reference, then you'd grab focus with:

```
(myInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).focus();
```

In some situations, you might need:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  (myInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).focus();
});
```

Comment: Thank you kshetline, I added the grab focus part in the child component, no effect yet (it's in the method triggered when I click the button). should I have placed it in the parent instead?

Comment: It's kind of hard to comment without seeing more of the code. The `@ViewChild` declaration has to be in whatever code has `#inputId` declared in its template. If `myInput` is defined, then you've got it in the right place. Then your event handler should be in the same class too, in order to see `myInput`. Were you getting any console errors, or just no result at all?

Comment: I added above the suggestion that you might want to use `setTimeout` before requesting focus.

Comment: Wow. It worked with the setTimeout!! But why? I would never have figured it out. Thank you kshetline!

Comment: Your event handler might not be the only event handler responding to the click event. Another event handler for that click might in fact request focus for the element that was clicked on, and if it does that after your focus request on the input field, the last such request will get priority. Using `setTimeout` ensures that the focus request for the input field happens last.

Comment: Can you explain what that does? Why it's needed? (myInput.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement)

Comment: @Andrew Koper, I'm not sure if in the ancient past of 18 months ago this typecasting was necessary, or if it just to forced stricter type checking. In my current Angular 9 code, `nativeElement` is type `any`, so this code would work without casting to `HTMLInputElement`, but even so, the casting does ensure that you don't accidentally use a method or a method signature that doesn't exist.